# FourCC as int C#

Tags: c#, fourcc

I am working with an SDK which requires an AVI codec be passed as an 8 digit int representation of the FourCC value. The FourCC value is WVC1 and I have tried converting the ASCII to the corresponding int values for each character which I figured would be 87864301, but this is incorrect.

Does anyone know is there a standard set of integer values representing FourCC values, or some way to convert it?

Comment: Does this help:  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd375802(v=vs.85).aspx

Answer (score 3, accepted):

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd375802(v=vs.85).aspx
suggests the characters of the FOURCC need to be hex values, and reversed prior to conversion.

Here's a sample console app using that matches their values for YUY2 (WVC1 = 31435657).
Updated code to include big/little endian and GUID conversions.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace FourCC
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string fourCC = "YUY2";

            Console.WriteLine("Big endian value of {0} is {1}", fourCC, ConvertFourCC(fourCC, toBigEndian:true));
            Console.WriteLine("Little endian value of {0} is {1}", fourCC, ConvertFourCC(fourCC));
            Console.WriteLine("GUID value of {0} is {1}", fourCC, ConvertFourCC(fourCC, toGuid:true));
            Console.ReadKey();

        }

        static string ConvertFourCC(string fourCC, bool toBigEndian = false, bool toGuid = false)
        {
            if (!String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(fourCC))
            {
                if (fourCC.Length != 4)
                {
                    throw new FormatException("FOURCC length must be four characters");                    
                }
                else
                {
                    char[] c = fourCC.ToCharArray();

                    if (toBigEndian)
                    {
                        return String.Format("{0:X}", (c[0] << 24| c[1] << 16 | c[2] << 8 | c[3]));
                    }
                    else if (toGuid)
                    {
                        return String.Format("{0:X}", (c[3] << 24) | (c[2] << 16) | (c[1] << 8) | c[0]) + "-0000-0010-8000-00AA00389B71";
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        return String.Format("{0:X}", (c[3] << 24) | (c[2] << 16) | (c[1] << 8) | c[0]);
                    }
                }
            }
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```